# Unit testing: SUNPKCS11 config dll functions

Tags: java, security, unit-testing, encryption, bouncycastle

I have developed an application using `sunpkcs11` and bouncycastle libraries for encrypting, signing, decryption and verifying a `cmsMessage`. I am using a Nexus smart card reader for keeping my private key and cryptography functions. My code is working fine, however I need to test my code for every possible scenarios which my users may encounter.

I want to test the functions inside the wrapper dll which is used in pkcs11 config file (in my case it is `Personal.dll` for Nexus smart card). How can I do it? I mean in my code I call some methods like `getInstance()`, `getContent()`,... and these functions belong to `sunpkcs11` and `bouncycastle` libraries, so if I want to generate a unit test, should I write my tests around these functions?

**EDIT1:**
The `Prsonal.dll` has been changed in this project by some other developers and I do not have access to its source code. I want to check the correct functionality with unit testing.

Comment: Why do you want to test them (the code you did not write) in the first place?

Comment: Because the Personal.dll has been changed for this project by some developers, and I have to use this manipulated library. Actually, I have no access to the dll source code and all I need is testing the functionality. @OlegEstekhin